# What is the official Ubuntu server AMI?

Tags: server, amazon-ec2

I would like to use the latest Ubuntu server on Amazon EC2.

What are the right AMI for me to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the official Ubuntu AMI's at https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/